# geany output to same terminal instance

Tags: bash, python, geany

In Geany, the *Menu > Build > Execute* command can be configured to send output to a terminal window.

For example: With the following command in *Build Commands* and a Python script in the active window, the *Execute* command will send output from the script into an interactive Python session in a terminal window.

```sh
/usr/bin/python3 -i '%f'
```

However, with Geany as I've configured it so far, the output goes to a new instance of terminal each time I run. I will quickly accumulate an unwieldy number of windows and if I want to see the result of a previous run it is not always obvious which window is the one.

So is there any way of getting this all to happen in the same terminal instance each time I run?

This is *not* about multiple instances of Geany, but about one instance of Geany generating multiple instances of terminal. The behavior I'm looking for is that of IDLE's <kbd>F5</kbd>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Geany's manual on [Virtual terminal emulator (VTE)](https://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html#terminal-vte-preferences) page and check *Execute programs in VTE* option:

> Execute programs in the virtual terminal instead of using the external terminal tool. Note that if you run multiple execute commands at once the output may become mixed together in the VTE.

Comment: IMHO, this is not a Ubuntu related question

Comment: Questions about software development and its tools *using Ubuntu* are on topic here. It's not clear cut at which point a question looses its connection to Ubuntu to a point where it ceases to be on topic but I'd say this one still is.

Comment: I can run once. If I run again I get this error   

    `` SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> >>>   File "<stdin>", line 1
    /bin/sh /tmp/geany_run_script_18KBKZ.sh``

Comment: I never encountered this `geany_run_script.sh` kind of error. Is it happening with different scripts or only with the same?

Comment: What's new? Is the question answered or this solutions is not working?

Comment: @freezed No this solution does not meet my requirements. I might work with it if there is some way of having the VTE open into a new window. Is that possible?

Comment: I am not sure to understand, the _Virtual terminal emulator (VTE) page_ is the place to configure script execution in the embedded terminal frame or in a separate window. Can you reformulate what do you need?